# How many Multiple Windows Boot can you have?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-xp

OK , I have heard about single boot , double boot and triple boot. I was wondering how many window boots can I have. Will having many boots affect my computer in anyway . Will I need more RAM for more Window boots Please clarify your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there's theoretically no limit.

Although you might have to install a seperate bootloader, as I'm not sure what the default Windows one will be happy to handle.

You do not need additional RAM for each system (only the one OS that you boot to will use any resources for that session) - but each system will need it's own partition on a hard drive, so you may need additional space.

---

If you intend to have lots of seperate OS's may I recommend you look at virtual machines as an option?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a limit. As DMA... said you should think about using a seperate boot loader. Another idea is if you are using a different harddisc for every os you can install your os'es so that every harddrive has it own (default) bootloader and choose from which harddisc to boot every time you start the computer. Usually its f8 button at start, but there isn't really a standard. This would have the advantage over a boot loader in the way, that if the harddrive with the boot loader get disabled/broken you will not be able to use any os until you fix it. With the boot from option only one os will not be bootable. Returning to the question, this way there is a limit based on how many harddiscs you can build in in your computer.